# How to ssh-forward ports <1024 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, port, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to set up an SSH tunnel on Windows 10 (version `10.0.19041.508`, the built-in OpenSSH is `OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5`) and I have the following error:

```
PS C:\> ssh root@example.com -p 2223 -i key.private.openssh -L 127.0.0.2:443:192.168.10.2:443
Privileged ports can only be forwarded by root.
```

I tried a PS and `cmd` shell (normal user and elevated to Administrator) - always the same issue.

This is a (vague) protection inherited from Unix systems but running the commander in a privileged context should have solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to this ([link](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1350)), I guess you need to update OpenSSH.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting OpenSSH to follow the versions but no. I installed manually the latest version.

Comment: How do you update it past 7.7p1? Even reinstalling it doesn't seem to take it past that version.